# Show shortcuts for actions in Thunar

Tags: shortcuts, gui, xfce, thunar

Is there a way to display the shortcuts in Thunar (or other Xfce stuff), if any? I know that the shortcuts can be specified in file `accels.scm`. All of them are set to default and commented out so anyone can change them. However that's not the point.

For example, renaming files. The shortcut is <kbd>F2</kbd>. But it is not showing it in the right-click menu. There is just the text "Rename...".

In menu bar, regardless of Thunar or any random application I have checked, each menu has the shortcuts shown right next to the respective actions.

Can I make Thunar to behave like that in a right-click menu?

Comment: Not possible in my experience, but there is a workaround for Thunar. My answer is "yes and no" as below.

Answer (score 2):

I have a mixed answer: Yes and no.

Yes, albeit a workaround, when creating a custom action in Thunar. No, because this workaround works for additional right-click menu in Thunar but *not* for existing entries of menu.

### Possible workaround

In Thunar file manager, click on **Edit** > **Configure Custom Actions...** then a small window will appear as shown below. For example, I have created a custom menu called "Toggle menu bar".

[image: Thunar's Custom Actions window]

Notice that the shortcut text "(Ctrl+M)" is added to the name of custom menu. This can be done in **Edit Action** (the pencil icon) > **Basic** tab and edit text field **Name**.

[image: Edit Action dialog]

This will result the right-click menu in Thunar to look like below.

[image: Thunar right-click menu with custom action]

### Useful for once, but useless in general

The workaround above is useful to show/hide menu bar. Because once user hides the menu bar in Thunar, there is no clue to restore from the default right-click menu or toolbar. Unless, the user remembers to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> keys to restore or press <kbd>F10</kbd> key to show menu bar temporarily.

On the other hand, showing the shortcut for the action in right-click menu is mostly useless. This is not just Thunar, but applies to almost any application in general. In fact, I have never seen any application in Linux or Windows that behaves so.